# Reaching bottom of ScrollViewer - maximum VerticalOffset value is lower than ScrollableHeight

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, scrollviewer, vertical-scrolling

I have problem with detecting when user reached the bottom of a ScrollViewer.

My Code:

```
bool atBottom = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
```

But sometimes when I reached the bottom of Scrollviewer, value of scrollViewer.VerticalOffset is lower than scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight. It depends on items in listbox, but I dont know how.

Do you know, where is the problem?

Comment: Can you post your xaml code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use this approach to detect reaching the bottom of the scrollviewer. Instead you should use the Scroll states to detect this.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx

Comment: All correct! But when it comes to WP8, e.g. VerticalCompression doesn't seem to work... Do you know any other possible solution for this in wp8 maybe?

Comment: Finally worked it around by using scroll states and checking if VerticalOffset is equal to ScrollableHeight