# See if scrollviewer is at the top of page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I use this code to see if a scrollviewer is at the bottom of the page.

```
private void OnScrollViewerUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var verticalOffset = sv.VerticalOffset;
        var maxVerticalOffset = sv.ExtentHeight - sv.ViewportHeight;

        if (maxVerticalOffset < 0 ||
            verticalOffset == maxVerticalOffset)
        {
            swipe_next();
        }


    }
```

How can I see if the scrollviewer is on top of the page?? And if the scrollviewer is at the bottom of the page, is it possible to go to the top?

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx) you can scroll to top using the method `ScrollToVerticalOffset(double d)`

So your method call should like this:

```
//scroll to top:
sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
```

If a vertical offset of 0 is the top of your viewport, then you could just check this by using something along this lines:

```
if(sv.VerticalOffset == 0)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to keep a track where the pointer has been pressed and the `scrollviewer` manipulation completed event.

This is just a sample, give a try with this snippet.

```
 // Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ListVerticalOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListVerticalOffset", typeof(double), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(OnListVerticalOffsetChanged));

    YourScrollViewer.Loaded += YourScrollViewer_Loaded;
}

void YourScrollViewer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var binding = new Binding
        {
            Source = YourScrollViewer,
            Path = new PropertyPath("VerticalOffset"),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        };
    SetBinding(ListVerticalOffsetProperty, binding);
}

private void OnListVerticalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var atBottom = YourScrollViewer.VerticalOffset >=   YourScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
    if (atBottom) MessageBox.Show("End");
}

public readonly DependencyProperty ListVerticalOffsetProperty;

public double ListVerticalOffset
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ListVerticalOffsetProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ListVerticalOffsetProperty, value); }
}
```

Have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697704/scrollviewer-reaching-bottom-windowsphone8?lq=1) too.